# Ansible archive remove option is not woking

Tags: ansible

I have to archive a directory on remote host and remove the directory once .tgz file is successfully created. I have the following in my playbook:

```
—-
- hosts: remote_hostName
  archive: 
    path: /test/folderA
    dest: /test/tmp/folderA.tgz
    remove: True
  register: result
```

I can see my /test/tmp/folderA.tgz being created. However, /test/folderA is still there even I set remove option as True. I am using Ansible 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

give `become: True` a try. So you have no problems with rights.

Comment: Thanks @Oliver. I tired, it did not work. I also change folderA mode to ‘777’ for the full access privileges, it still did not work.

Comment: I have found https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/issues/3537 .  So you should add a `/` at the end of your path.

Comment: Thanks! I saw this post earlier as well and tried already. The wired thing is that it only removed some files not all under folderA. I had register: result (see updated post). I don’t see any files listed in return value of missed, I.e:  missed: []. So I assum all files/ subdirectories were archived. But if I remove folderA.tgz file and run archive again for the files still left in folderA, I see register return value- archived: []. So it looks like whatever the files/ subdirectories could not be removed at 1st try were the files may have not be archived. That”s why thay’re still there.